# Finding expected value with binomial distribution

Tags: probability, expectation

Im having a bit of trouble with this problem:
$X\sim Bin(10,0.75)$
I need to find the expected value of $17x-6.4$.

First I thought about using the linearity properties, but i think linearity is only valid in uniform distribution and not in Binomial.
So what is the trick here?

Comment: the linearity property is applicable to summation, integration, etc. So expectation also share this property.

Comment: what if i need to find the expectancy of x^2? in this case i cant use linearity right? if so then what is the course of action?

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y$ be arbitrary random varibles,

$E(X+Y)=EX+EY$

So $EX=10 \times 0.75=7.5$ Hence $E(17X-6.4)=17 \times 7.5-6.4=121.1$